# Image with fixed height and 100% width

Tags: html, css, svg

I really cant get this image to stretch 100% horizontally with a fixed height. I don't care about distortion, because it's just a svg pattern. I've tried both with an img-tag and a div, with the svg as background, but nothing seems to work. What i got right now is this:

```css
.divider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(../images/wave.svg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

EDIT:

Screenshot for clarification

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to accomplish this without distorting the image. The only way to create the "appearance" of this, would be to allow the image to scale horizontally and use the containing element to dictate the maximum height, eventually leading to cutting part of the image off.

EDIT:

> In lieu of the op wanting distortion, the best method is to set background-size with width 100% and fixed height of 50px

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2hu74z8k/

`<div class="image-height-fixed"></div>
.image-height-fixed {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=13&txt=500%C3%9750&w=500&h=50);
  background-size: 100% 50px;
}`

Comment: I've just added a screenshot to my question. I WANT to make it distort. It's a wavy divider for my sections, and when I make it 100% width it's too tall. I just want to make it fill the width of the screen with a fixed height.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I've updated the code snippet and Fiddle.

Comment: It still doesn't work as it supposed to, it sort of cuts off the bottom of the SVG. http://i.imgur.com/wmOWOrt.png

Comment: @bjarkof are you sure your PNG is the correct size (I've seen similar Qs on SO where the asker has had the wrong sized image!)? Set CSS `box-sizing` to `content` incase padding and border values are also making up the overall height value.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
height:100vh;
```

its for vieport height.

there is also vw for vieport witdth.

but watch out especially ios cant handle it.. so for ios devices set a fixed height.

[some further informations about vh](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)

[can i use vw, vh?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

greetings timotheus

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need as much browser support as possible, so unfortunatly this isn't an option.

Comment: its the best way with css.. otherwise you have to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
background-size: 100% 50px;
```

EDIT: PimBrouwers beat me to it.